# How do I solve this error within my code: ValueError: 'l' is not in list, error

Tags: python, list, syntax

```
print("welcome to hangman")
number_left = 1
answer_input = input()
answer = []

for i in range(len(answer_input)):
    answer.append(answer_input[i])
print(answer)
guessed = []
number_of_underscores = 0
length = len(answer)
for i in range(length):
    guessed.append("_")
while True:
    for i in guessed:
        if i != "_":
            number_of_underscores = number_of_underscores + 1
            if number_of_underscores == length:
                break

    guess = input("Guess your letter")
    actual_number_left = answer.count(guess) + 1
    if guess not in answer:
        print("incorrect")
        output_answer = " ".join(guessed)
        print(output_answer)
    else:
        if answer.count(guess) > 1:
            while number_left != 0:                
                position = answer.index(guess)
                answer[position] = "_"
                number_left = actual_number_left - 1
                guessed[position] = guess
                if number_left == 0:                    
                    output_answer = " ".join(guessed)
                    print(output_answer)
                    break
        else:
            for i in answer:
                if i == guess:
                    index_number = answer.index(guess)
                    guessed[index_number] = guess
                    output_answer = " ".join(guessed)
                    print(output_answer)
                    break
```

Im trying to fix my hangman code so that if my answer was "hello" and i guessed "l" then both letters should appear  when printing the output_answer. But I am getting a error in line 29 where it says position = answer.index(guess)

This raises the error ValueError: 'l' is not in list
I know that it is in my list because it I printed the list at the start and l was in it. I cant tell if I am just being dumb or if im just missing something, either way, it would be much appreciated if you could spot the mistake. Thanks!

Comment: no it is all lowercase, just like the input at the start

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sid\Documents\Python projects\hangman.py", line 154, in <module>
    position = answer.index(guess)
ValueError: 'l' is not in list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending code:

```
while number_left != 0:
    position = answer.index(guess)
    answer[position] = "_"
    number_left = actual_number_left - 1
    guessed[position] = guess
    if number_left == 0:
        output_answer = " ".join(guessed)
        print(output_answer)
        break
```

The error takes place on this line specifically: `position = answer.index(guess)`. I've pasted the whole while-loop, though, because the whole thing could use some restructuring.

The main problem is that this while-loop has an excessive number of iterations. The loop does not end until `number_left == 0`. Initially, `number_left` is set to `1`, so we know the loop will run at least once, which is fine. However, the only place in the while-loop where `number_left` changes is in this line:

`number_left = actual_number_left - 1`

If `answer_input` was "hello" (and `answer` is therefore `["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]`), and I guess the letter "l", then `actual_number_left` will be `3`. `actual_number_left` never changes to a different value in this while-loop, so `number_left` will take on the value of `2` each iteration. This means, the while-loop does not end. For each iteration of the loop, you replace the next-found instance of the guessed letter with an underscore. This won't cause any problems for the first two iterations, since "hello" has two l's, but on the third iteration `str.index` will throw a `ValueError` exception, since there are no more l's left to replace.